# How to get Categories from Tridion using categoriesdata

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I was looking for a way that how can I fetch all the categories from Tridion using Categoriesdata. I was trying like below, but its showing error.

```
CoreServiceSession client = new CoreServiceSession();
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient csClient = client.GetClient();
ReadOptions readoption = new ReadOptions();

CategoriesFilterData filter = new CategoriesFilterData();
XElement xml = csClient.GetSystemWideList(filter);
```

Comment: I noticed in this and previous code samples that you create a `CoreServiceSession` object. Just out of curiosity: what is that class and where does it come from? You don't seem to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use GetListXml instead of GetSystemWideList and specify the publication ID from which you want to retrieve the categories:

```
CategoriesFilterData filterData = new CategoriesFilterData();
XElement resultXml = client.GetListXml(publicationId, filterData);
```

GetSystemWideList is usually for retrieving stuff that is system wide and not bound to just 1 publication, like PublicationTargets and MultimediaTypes

You could however also try a Search query, like so:

```
SearchQueryData filter = new SearchQueryData(); 
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Category }; 

IdentifiableObjectData[] results = client.GetSearchResults(filter);
foreach (IdentifiableObjectData obj in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", obj.Title, obj.Id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reinder, but what if i need to get all the catagories from tridion not from a specific publication.

Comment: Ah, OK.
you could try using SearchQueryData and search within tridion.

Comment: like so:

SearchQueryData filter = new SearchQueryData();
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Category };
filter.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended;

IdentifiableObjectData[] results = client.GetSearchResults(filter);